# Instruments for detecting leaks

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, instruments

Is there a video that goes through how to use Instruments and find leaks? I looked on youtube and couldn't find any. My code leaks because in instruments I see a red line in leaks section but I dont' know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Stanford iTunes U in "Developing apps for iOS fall 2010" is video "Debugging Tools..." There is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the WWDC videos from 2010/2011. They're available through the Apple Developer program. There's a lot of great coverage on the tools at your disposal.

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/